# React div container onClick conflicts with checkbox onChange

Tags: reactjs

In the following React class I have a checkbox within a div container.  I want a click on the container to toggle the checkbox.  I also *think* I need to bind the onChange of the checkbox input itself, to handle things like when the user is tab/spacing to toggle the state of the checkbox (I also get a warning from React if I *don't* specify an onChange because this is a controlled component).

My problem is that *both* of the event handlers fire when I click the checkbox itself, so the state of the checkbox doesn't actually change.  I have tried e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation in handleCheckboxChange but neither seems to do anything.

```
export default class Item extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            IsSelected: false
        }
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <div className="item">
                <div className="checkbox-container" onClick={this.handleContainerClick.bind(this)}>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.IsSelected} onChange={this.handleCheckboxChange.bind(this)} />
                </div>                  
            </div>
        );
    }
    handleCheckboxChange(e){
        this.setState({
            IsSelected: !this.state.IsSelected
        });
    }
    handleContainerClick(){
        this.setState({
            IsSelected: !this.state.IsSelected
        });     }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want the containing `<div>` to be in "control" of the checkbox's value, then don't put any handler on the checkbox itself.  React will make sure the container will receive the childs `click` events.

```
var CheckboxInClickableBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      checked: false
    };
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        <span>{"Checked: " + this.state.checked}</span>

        <br />

        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} />
      </div>
    );
  },
  onClick: function () {
    this.setState({
      checked: !this.state.checked
    });
  }
});
```

[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pogejihapa/1/edit?js,output) - clicking anywhere in the green box will trigger a toggle.

Also, HTML dictates that a `<label>` with a `for="pie"` attribute will pass `click` events to any `<input id="pie">`.  This can appear to "break" your checkbox when using the method above - eg:

```
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div onClick={this.onClick}>
        <label htmlFor="pie">{"Checked: " + this.state.checked}</label>

        <br />

        <input id="pie" type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Clicking the `<label>` will behave as if there were 2 click events:

- the first is the original `click` event bubbling from the `<label>` to the `<div>` and triggering our `onClick` handler
- the second is the `<label>` "delegating" its click to the `<input>` element, due to the `for` attribute (`htmlFor` in React), which then bubbles up and hits our `onClick` handler

[Example on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/cayucinequ/1/edit?js,output) - clicking anywhere in the box *except the `<label>`* will trigger a toggle.  Clicking the `<label>` will trigger 2 toggles.

Comment: One problem with setting the onClick on the div only is that React will always log a warning about having an input without an onChange handler.  Now that you mention the htmlFor attribute, I think the correct thing to do is set my container to a <label> instead of a div and set the htmlFor on that.  I tried it in my app and it works like I want it to.  The onChange handler is set on the input but clicking the container toggles the checkbox state as well.

Comment: Glad I could help. Regarding the `onChange` handler: The warning provided by React only appears if you skip the `onChange` handler AND supply a `value` property, as an `input` with a static value is likely (though not always) indicative of a design flaw.  This warning has helped me a couple of times when I've forgotten to add `onChange={this.onChange}` to an input, for example.

Comment: Right, but in this case I am supplying a value property because this is a controlled component.

Comment: @Sean I walked into a similar use-case and I solved it by adding a readOnly property to the checkbox.