# React/HTML cancel onClick from parent <div> when a child checkbox <input> is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

My question pertains to React code, but it's possible that the answer is more related to how HTML Events function in general rather than React.

I am building a component where any click inside of the enclosing `<div>` should trigger a specific click handler. This is easily implemented as an `onClick` function attached to this "parent div". The component also contains a checkbox inside of it. Due to the business rules of this component, I desire to not have the parent div's `onClick` get triggered by a click of this checkbox.

Consider this naive implementation of this component:

```
function NaiveComponent() {
  return (
    <div onClick={() => console.log("Clicked parent onClick()")}>
      <label><input type="checkbox" /></label>
      <div> ... </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

What I've found interesting is that the `onClick` is triggered twice when the checkbox is changed, but only once otherwise. I've read articles that suggest that this is due to how label click's are propagated to the input element (as suggested by [React div container onClick conflicts with checkbox onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34644200/react-div-container-onclick-conflicts-with-checkbox-onchange)).

I've also tried to stop propagation of the click event by attaching the following capture handler to the input. It only stopped one of the calls to the parent `onClick` from triggering.

```
onClickCapture={e => e.stopPropagation()}
```

---

## Update

I completely redesigned the component so that the checkbox is no longer placed within the div with the click handler. It was a bad UI design in the first place. I think my click handler problems were caused by layers of libraries that my application uses for styling. It should have been apparent to me that what I was doing was a code smell to begin with, based on the difficulty I was facing.

Thank you everyone who gave an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const App = () => {
  const onCheckboxClick = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('checkbox clicked');
  }

  return (
    <div onClick={() => alert('div clicked')}>
      This is the parent div
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" onClick={onCheckboxClick} />
      </label>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

This seems to work fine using `e.stopPropagation()`.  Can you show us more of your code if this doesn't help?

Answer (score 2):

Attaching an `onClick` to the input and stopping propagation should work. This only triggers the input click handler and not the parent one

```
function App(){
  return (<div 
    onClick={() => console.log('div clicked')} 
    style={{width: '100px', height:'100px', background: 'blue'}}>
    <input 
       onClick={e => {
         e.stopPropagation(); 
         console.log('check clicked')}} 
       type='checkbox'></input>
    </div>)
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```